# Responsive Picture Element still working even after being removed from DOM in Chrome Browser

Tags: image, element

Can anyone explain why the responsive picture image is still firing using Chrome Canary 42.0.2302.2 after it has been removed (works as expected in IE11 and FF 35.0.1 - in Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m it is broken, but interestingly, it also downloaded both images straight away!).

To test, open the test page with Chrome Dev Tools open on the Network tab. Take note of the image that has been displayed. Tap anywhere on the page to empty the content. Now resize the page and note that the other images are downloaded despite the picture element being removed from the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Picture Element</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <picture>
            <source srcset="http://placehold.it/768/f00/fff" media="(max-width: 768px)">
            <source srcset="http://placehold.it/992/0f0/fff" media="(max-width: 992px)">
            <img srcset="http://placehold.it/1200/00f/fff">
        </picture>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('body').on('click', function() {
                $('body').empty();
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

JSFiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/5qwLus59/4/

Answer (score 0):

Because Mutations aren't set up correctly in Chrome. It's similar to how people sometimes write their JS code.

For example:

```
$('.nav').each(function(){
    var $nav = $(this);
    var sizeNav = function(){
        //some code
    };
    $(window).on('resize', sizeNav);
});
```

In fact they should do something like this:

```
$('.nav').each(function(){
    var $nav = $(this);
    var sizeNav = function(){
        //some code
    };
    $(window).on('resize', sizeNav);
    $nav.on('remove', function(){
        //destroy code
        $(window).off('resize', sizeNav);
    });
});
```

This is a serious issue, please report this!:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues

Comment: Your main point is that this is a defect. I'll log one now and post defect number in a while. On your example, jQuery's empty method clears any event listeners. http://api.jquery.com/empty/ "To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves." But I guess you are only posting this as an analogy.

Comment: Link to Chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=458794 - will mark post as answered once I get some feedback. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: 1. of course I'm posting this as an analogy. 2. yes, if you remove the nav element all events bound to nav and to it's child elements are removed. window is not a child element! therefore you need to remove it manually...

Comment: Right, got ya - good point about window listener not being remove as not child of nav element.